# Javascript button click causing multiple Post

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following script which is rendering a partial view inside a dialog box:

```
$(function () {
            $('#addressLookupBtn').click(function () {                
            $('#dialog').dialog({
                title: 'Address Lookup Tool',
                modal: true,
                width: '1200',
                height: 'auto',
                resizable: false,
                show: {
                    effect: "fade",
                    duration: 2000
                },
                hide: {
                    effect: "fade",
                    duration: 1000
                },
                open: function (event, ui) {
                    //Load the AddressLookup action which will return
                    //the partial view: _AddressLookup

                    $(this).load("@Url.Action("AddressLookup", new { evpId = Model.EvpId })");

                }
            }).dialog('open');

        });
        });
```

The problem is, when I submit the partial view, there are 2 POSTS being made to the server, I think the submit for the partial view is also being bound to the `$('#addressLookupBtn').click`. Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

**more info**

[image]

**Partial view**

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "updatearea" }))
{
    <div id="updatearea" class="form-group">

        <div style="width:300px; display:block; float:left;">
            @Html.TextBox("PostCode", null, new { @class = "form-control" })            
        </div>

        <div id="NewAddressLine">

            <input type="submit" value="Lookup Postcode" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>    

}
```

Comment: you can may be add click event  at other place. that is  , $('#addressLookupBtn').click  may be  in one more than

Comment: Hard to guess without seeing what's going on with the partial, but if there's any funny stuff going on with nested click events, you can do: `$("#something").click(function(e) { e.stopPropagation(); ...theRestOfYourStuff... });`.

Comment: If required you can see my partial code in my previous question, although it is no longer posting 4 times, I sorted that by removing an extra Jquery reference, it now just posts twice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I didn't need to change anything other than move the following bundle reference from `_Layout` to my `Edit` view:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/unobtrusive-ajax")
```

Comment: Good that you found a way to still use both. I was correct in that it was a problem with the unobtrusive then, or rather that it got referenced "incorrectly".

Comment: @Mackan Yeah your suggestions helped me out so thanks, im sure your solution would have also worked but this was the easy fix for me so I'll flag it as the answer.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like the post is being submitted using both a normal form submit and as a jquery event.

Perhaps change it to a button (instead of submit) and use only the jquery submit, or remove the jquery event and use only the normal form submit.

**As per comments - An example of using jquery ajax instead of MS ajax:**

The script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  event.preventDefault(); // stop the form from submitting the normal way
  $('#MyForm').submit(function(event) {
    $.post(
        $('#MyForm').attr('action'), 
        { 'PostCode' : $('input[name=PostCode]').val() }
    )
    .done(function(data) {
        alert('Post worked, and data was returned. Parse and/or present.');
        $('#updatearea').html(data); //Replace the current contents of "updatearea" with the returned contents 
    });
  });

});
```

The PartialView:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("MyAction", "MyController", new { @id = "MyForm" }))
{
<div id="updatearea" class="form-group">

    <div style="width:300px; display:block; float:left;">
        @Html.TextBox("PostCode", null, new { @class = "form-control" })            
    </div>

    <div id="NewAddressLine">

        <input type="submit" value="Lookup Postcode" class="btn btn-default" />
    </div>
</div>    

}
```

Comment: I don't understand where the jquery event is coming from though and if I change the submit to a button nothing fires

Comment: @SelectDistinct Are you referencing jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js in your partial?

Comment: I have it in my _Layout @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/unobtrusive-ajax")

Comment: It might be a collision between the Microsoft ajax libs and jquery.unobtrusive. To make sure, you can try and remove the reference to unobtrusive, or change the Ajax.beginform to Html.beginform. Just to find the offending party.

Comment: Yeh if I swap Ajax.beginform to Html.Beginform I only get one post, but it opens in a new page rather than within the div/dialog

Comment: Ok, so the options are: Change the MS-ajax to jquery ajax (using $.ajax or $.post instead of ajax.beginform) or remove the ref. to jquery.unobtrusive if you can live without this. Optionally, if you know how, you can choose to include jquery.unobtrusive conditionally (not in places where you use ajax.beginform).

Comment: @Mackan can you provide a code snippet of swapping the Ajax.BeginForm

Comment: @SelectDistinct Added a code example. You might have to modify what it posts and what gets returned, but it should be quite clear how to do that I hope. You never mentioned WHERE you post to in your example, so i used "MyAction" and "MyController".

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are calling open, and still have autoOpen set to true (it is true by default). This is causing open event to run twice. Try setting autoOpen to false

```
$('#dialog').dialog({
    ...
    autoOpen: false,
    ...
});
```

https://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-autoOpen

Comment: Or remove `.dialog('open')`

Comment: I've now tried both these suggestions, I'm still getting two posts as per my update and image